# Why does an iterator need a cast for a generically defined lists

Tags: java, oop, generics, collections

```
class ZiggyTest{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        list.add(4);
        list.add(5);
        list.add(-5);

        for(Iterator i = list.iterator(); i.hasNext();){
            Integer in = i.next();
            System.out.println(in);
        }
    }

}
```

The above code example results in the following compiler error:

```
ZiggyTest.java:17: incompatible types
found   : java.lang.Object
required: java.lang.Integer
            Integer in = i.next();
                               ^
1 error
```

Why does the Iterator.next() method need a cast when the List associated with the Iterator is declared generically?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `Iterator.next()` result needs a cast precisely because the `Iterator` was incorrectly declared *without* a generic template type.

If you have a `List<Integer>` then the correct type for the iterator is `Iterator<Integer>`:

```
for (Iterator<Integer> i = list.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
    Integer in = i.next();
    System.out.println(in);
}
```

Alternatively, write:

```
for (Integer in: list) {
    System.out.println(in);
}
```

and avoid the explicit iterator altogether.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to avoid the cast, you need the generified version of the `Iterator`, which in your case is `Iterator<Integer>`. If you look at the javadoc of the [`List#iterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#iterator%28%29) method, you see it returns a generified version.

So just change your for-loop to

```
for(Iterator<Integer> i = list.iterator(); i.hasNext();)
```

and all will compile just fine.

The [Oracle example](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/generics-136597.html) illustrates the same issue as you just encountered. In ex1 a compile error is caused by the missing cast, and in ex2 this is solved by using the generified version of the iterator